# Java: Method name conventions

Tags: java, android, naming-conventions

This is more out of curiosity than anything else, just wondering what are the most common naming conventions for method names?

Start with a capital

```
GetName()
```

or start lowercase and then capitals for each new word

```
getName()
```

or something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java uses `camelCase` convention for method names.

You can read more about conventions in Java in this document: [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: Both versions under question actually are camel case. It should be mentioned that methods are lower camel case and classes upper camel case.

Comment: The first one is called "Pascal case". The camel case always starts with lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the convention is to have the first word with a lower case, and the rest with upper case.

`public void getName()`

Also, constants are declared in full capitals:

`public final int MAX_USERS`

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the naming convention for methods is getName()

Variables also follow the same naming convention as methods, for example. getNameExample

The naming convention used for classes capitalizes every word ex. GetName